# Correct sorting of \index entries containing macros

Tags: macros, indexing, sorting

I use `\index` in classical way, but also with some macros as content. More precisely, I have some macros like `\def\foo{BAR}`, and I use then `\index{\foo}`.

Unfortunately, the index is then order by the name of the macro, not the content of the macro. It's quite embarrassing since all the macros are in the top of the list (due to the use of `\`).

Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 5):

If you expand the macro before `\index` reads it the sorting should be correct after the content. You can do this using `\expandafter`:

```
  \def\foo{BAR}
  % ...
  \expandafter\index\expandafter{\foo}
```

It is shorter if you put the `{ }` inside the definition:

```
  \def\foo{{BAR}}
  % ...
  \expandafter\index\foo
```

For more complex content, i.e. with multiple macros you should expand the content fully using `\edef` (or maybe `\protected@edef`):

```
  \def\foo{BAR}
  \def\bar{FOO}
  % ...
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\index{\foo\bar}}
  \temp
```

If you want to keep the `\temp` definition local use:

```
  \begingroup
  \edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand\index{\foo\bar}}
  \temp
```

instead.

Comment: To trick with `\expandafter` does not work in my document. Maybe it's because I have a `\textsc` in the beginning of my `\def` ?

Comment: What "does not work" exactly? Is the sorting order still incorrect, you mean? I would need to see the full code. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: `\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{index} 

\title{}
\author{}

\makeindex

\def \px {{\textsc{Exact}\xspace}}
\expandafter\index\px

\begin{document}
Blah
\index{aaa}
\index{\px}
\index{zzz}

\printindex

\end{document}`

Comment: @bloub__: You need to write the index entry as `text@\format{text}` instead, i.e. `Exact@\textsc{Exact}`, to allow the index to be sorted correctly. I also wouldn't use `\xspace` for an index-only macro.

Comment: Thanks ! But unfortunately, there're not index-only macros -- I also use them in the text. I guess the simple way to solve my problem is to change every "classical" indexes by macros indexes !

Comment: @bloub__: In this cause I wouldn't put the `{ }` in the macro definition. The `\xspace` must be at the very end with nothing behind it.

Comment: OK, but the other problem is that I have Exact@EXACT if I put `\px` in my text...

Comment: @bloub__: I know, you simply need to have two different macros then, like `\px` and `\ipx`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex
    \def\Index#1{#1\expandafter\index\expandafter{#1}}
\begin{document}

\index{classical}
\def\foo{BAR} and I use then \foo\index{\foo} (the wrong entry)\newpage
 and \Index{\foo} (the correct entry).

\printindex 
\end{document}
```

The first entry is wrong the second with `\Index` correct:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, the index calls are done in a `\newcommand`, so I cannot make a difference between a classical one and a `\def` one.

Comment: `\Index{foo}` is the same as `foo\expandafter\index\expandafter{foo}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Martin Sharrer's solution (above).

All the index keys AAAAA to HHHHH are sorted in alphabetical order, regardless of their original format (newcommand, def, bfseries, etc.) whereas ZZZZZ is not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeindex%
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\BBBBB}[0]{BBBBB}
\newcommand{\DDDDD}[0]{DDDDD}
\def\EEEEE{EEEEE}
\def\FFFFF{FFFFF}
\def\HHHHH{HHHHH}
\newcommand{\ZZZZZ}[0]{ZZZZZ}

Here is an example of Martin Sharrer's solution (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18336/correct-sorting-of-index-entries-containing-macros).
All the index keys AAAAA to HHHHH are sorted in alphabetical order, regardless of their original format (newcommand, def, bfseries, etc.) whereas ZZZZZ is not. 

\index{AAAAA@\bfseries AAAAA \normalfont}
\expandafter\index\expandafter{\BBBBB}
\index{CCCCC}
 \expandafter\index\expandafter{\DDDDD}
 \expandafter\index\expandafter{\EEEEE @ \scshape \EEEEE \normalfont}
 \expandafter\index\expandafter{\FFFFF}
\index{GGGGG@\color{red} GGGGG \color{black}\normalfont}
 \expandafter\index\expandafter{\HHHHH}
 \index{\ZZZZZ}% sorted according to its "\"

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]