# imakeidx: Order if own command is used to specify index entry

Tags: macros, indexing, sorting, imakeidx

I have a question concerning the order in an index created with [`imakeidx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx?lang=de). I wanted to define my own commands for index entry names  with `\newcommand{$VARIABLENAME}{$VARIABLEVALUE}` in order to reuse them in the whole document.

However, if I do that, the order in the index is created by the name of the command rather than the content. I found that the index-files use the command and not the content.

How can I circumvent this?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\indexsetup{%
  level=\section*,%
  toclevel=section,%
}

\newcommand{\idxKeywordName}{Keyword}

\makeindex[%
  name=\idxKeywordName,%
  title=\idxKeywordName{} index,
  intoc,
]

\newcommand{\idxKwEntryA}{A}
\newcommand{\idxKwEntryB}{B}
\newcommand{\idxKwEntryC}{C}
\newcommand{\idxKwEntryD}{Z} % why is this entry not in order?
\newcommand{\idxKwEntryE}{E}
\newcommand{\idxKwEntryF}{F}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Item A \index[\idxKeywordName]{\idxKwEntryA}
  \item Item B \index[\idxKeywordName]{\idxKwEntryB}
  \item Item C \index[\idxKeywordName]{\idxKwEntryC}
  \item Item D \index[\idxKeywordName]{\idxKwEntryD}
  \item Item E \index[\idxKeywordName]{\idxKwEntryE}
  \item Item F \index[\idxKeywordName]{\idxKwEntryF}
\end{itemize}

\printindex[\idxKeywordName]

\end{document}
```

The resulting index looks like this:

[image]

where the `Z` entry is obviously not where it is supposed to be. I found the reason for the "wrong" order in the `idx`-file:

```
\indexentry{\idxKwEntryA}{1}
\indexentry{\idxKwEntryB}{1}
\indexentry{\idxKwEntryC}{1}
\indexentry{\idxKwEntryD}{1}
\indexentry{\idxKwEntryE}{1}
\indexentry{\idxKwEntryF}{1}
```

Here, the index entry is defined by the command `\idxKwEntryX` rather than its content. This gives the `ind`-file:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item \idxKwEntryA, 1
  \item \idxKwEntryB, 1
  \item \idxKwEntryC, 1
  \item \idxKwEntryD, 1
  \item \idxKwEntryE, 1
  \item \idxKwEntryF, 1

\end{theindex}
```

Here is what I would suspect based on the MWE for the `ilg`-file:

```
\indexentry{A}{1}
\indexentry{B}{1}
\indexentry{C}{1}
\indexentry{Z}{1}
\indexentry{E}{1}
\indexentry{F}{1}
```

and the `ind`-file:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item A, 1
  \item B, 1
  \item C, 1
  \item E, 1
  \item F, 1
  \item Z, 1

\end{theindex}
```

Why is that and how can I get an order based on the actual content?

---

### Update

Similar question: [Correct sorting of \index entries containing macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18336/correct-sorting-of-index-entries-containing-macros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort the index according to content, the arguments need to be expanded. An easy way to expand an argument is to pass it through an identity function:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\newcommand{\idxKeywordName}{Keyword}

\newcommand{\nindex}[2][]{\index[#1]{#2}}

\makeindex[name=\idxKeywordName,title=\idxKeywordName{} index,columns=1]

\newcommand{\idxKwEntryA}{A}
\newcommand{\idxKwEntryB}{Z}
\newcommand{\idxKwEntryC}{C}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item A \nindex[\idxKeywordName]{\idxKwEntryA}
  \item Item B \nindex[\idxKeywordName]{\idxKwEntryB}
  \item Item C \nindex[\idxKeywordName]{\idxKwEntryC}
\end{itemize}

\printindex[\idxKeywordName]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the entries are now separated by an `\indexspace` (i.e., small vertical space) because the different initial characters are recognized, as opposed to the original example where all the entries are in the same group.