# Index entries sorted by text of macro instead of value

Tags: macros, glossaries, indexing, sorting, makeidx

A [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18336/correct-sorting-of-index-entries-containing-macros) was asked here seven years ago, but I couldn't manage to make that solution work in my case.

I am using macros in various instances of my text to have a shorthand for often used terms but also to automatically build an index from them.
Because my use case requires the first instance of each use be treated differently than the rest, I used the glossaries package.

However, when I build an index from them, they get sorted by the plain text of the macro, not the result of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
  \makeindex
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newcommand{\MacroToIndex}[1]{\gls{#1}\index{\gls{#1}}}
  \newacronym{aaaa}{AAAA}{AAAA}
  \newacronym{bbbb}{ZZZZ}{ZZZZ}
  \newacronym{cccc}{CCCC}{CCCC}
\begin{document}
\MacroToIndex{aaaa}, \MacroToIndex{bbbb}, \MacroToIndex{cccc}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

In this case the resulting index is:

> AAAA, 1
>
> ZZZZ, 1 *<- This is \gls{bbbb}*
>
> CCCC, 1

Is there any way to make the index sort them correctly? The linked thread suggests \expandafter but I could not wrap my head around how to apply it in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `\makeindex` and `\printindex`, but `\makeglossaries` and `\printglossaries`.

After running LaTeX on the document, run `makeglossaries` rather than `makeindex` and rerun LaTeX.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\MacroToIndex}[1]{\gls{#1}\index{\gls{#1}}}

\newacronym{aaaa}{AAAA}{AAAAfirst}
\newacronym{bbbb}{ZZZZ}{ZZZZfirst}
\newacronym{cccc}{CCCC}{CCCCfirst}

\begin{document}

\MacroToIndex{aaaa}, \MacroToIndex{bbbb}, \MacroToIndex{cccc}

\MacroToIndex{aaaa}, \MacroToIndex{bbbb}, \MacroToIndex{cccc}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

I use makeidx because those macros actually belong to different categories and I need to keep them indexed separatedly.. I left it out for brevity, but actually the macros are closer to:  \newcommand{\MacroToIndexONE}[1]{\gls{#1}\index{ONE!\gls{#1}}}   and  \newcommand{\MacroToIndexTWO}[1]{\gls{#1}\index{TWO!gls{#1}}}  and so on.

As far as I am aware, I can only have one glossary, right?

Comment: @AndreasPuhl It's not really clear what you're trying to do. There can be any number of glossaries.

Comment: I must have overlooked that. I will refer back to the glossaries manual and mark your reply as correct. Thank you!